# pandas: how to get pandas.compare() to return all columns of the other row?

Tags: python, pandas

With dataframes `df_a` and `df_b`, how do I return the difference (meaning, the data in `other` at variance with `self`) as complete rows (e.g., all columns)?  If I do

```
first = {
    'Name': ['Bob', 'Mike', 'Alex'],
    'Job': ['Forklift Operator', 'Forklift Operator', 'Master Forklift Operator']
}

second = {
    'Name': ['Bob', 'Mike', 'Allen'],
    'Job': ['Forklift Operator', 'Forklift Operator', 'Master Forklift Operator']

df_a = pd.DataFrame(first)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(second)

df_c = df_a.compare(df_b)
print(df_c)
```

that gives me

```
    Name
    self  other
2   Alex  Allen
```

What I would like to be able to get is the entire row from `other` that does not match the left:

```
    Name                       Job
2  Allen  Master Forklift Operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_b.loc[df_a.compare(df_b).index]
```

Output:

```
    Name                       Job
2  Allen  Master Forklift Operator
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `right` type of merge (right frame) and `indicator` feature:

```
df_c = (pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='right', indicator=True)
        .pipe(lambda x: x[x['_merge'].eq('right_only')].drop('_merge', axis=1)))
print(df_c)
```

---

```
    Name                       Job
2  Allen  Master Forklift Operator
```